# Why does Simple_Form's association method throw the "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form

The association method from simple_form is throwing an exception on the most basic use, and I cannot figure out why. I'd appreciate any help.

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many association between the Users and Projects models:

project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  ...
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :projects_owned, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  ...
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, input_html: { size: 61 } %>
    <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: { cols: 60 } %>
    <%= f.association(:users) %>
    <%= f.submit "Save project", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

All models have corresponding tables, and the association works correclty in Rspec tests and the Rails console.

When I build the form, exactly [as specified in the simple_form documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations), I get the following error:

```
<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)>
```

Stack trace:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1):
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_input.rb:87:in `collection_includes_basic_objects?'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_input.rb:70:in `detect_common_display_methods'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_input.rb:57:in `detect_collection_methods'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_select_input.rb:5:in `input'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:29:in `block in render'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb:27:in `render'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/wrappers/root.rb:15:in `render'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:120:in `input'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb:212:in `association'
  app/views/projects/edit.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_projects_edit_html_erb___630637963_32694600'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:435:in `form_for'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:22:in `block in simple_form_for'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:41:in `with_simple_form_field_error_proc'
  simple_form (3.0.1) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:21:in `simple_form_for'
  app/views/projects/edit.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_projects_edit_html_erb___630637963_32694600'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__482912548__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__957210712__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Sure, and thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has something to do with the collection for the form field.

See if this works:

```
<%= f.association :users, collection: User.all %>
```

I haven't tracked down why the collection is needed yet, but that seems to be the problem.